# In order to see a page I want the user to subscribe to our newsletter

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I would like to let only subscribed users/guest to see the content of a page.
How can I achieve this? I also want that if is not subscribed to appear the form to subscribe and then to be able to see the page.

Comment: are you want to list newsletter subscriber??

Comment: do you want this for guest users or registered users?

Comment: @MTM - As I said in the description, I want for both: guests and customers, also loggedin or not.

Comment: I don't think this will be possible for guests. I don't see how you can verify a guest has signed up for future visits. If a guest doesn't create an account on your site they will be force to subscribe each time they visit.

Comment: @StevenLynn - hmm..I think I can verify - at least after he tries to subscribe again :) or something using cookies...I am not sure right now

Comment: @Denisa Possibly. Seems extremely annoying for the customer. I personally would never use a site that forced me to sign up for the newsletter.

Comment: @StevenLynn Me neither, but it is not up to me. Also, we are talking here about only one page not the whole site.

Comment: @Denisa For some reason the one page think didn't process in my mind. I thought you meant to visit any page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can a customer is subscriber or  not by using 
below code**

`$subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByCustomer($customer)`;
Where $csutomer is customer object

**Or**

get list of subscriber using below code

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceSingleton('newsletter/subscriber_collection')
 ->showCustomerInfo(true)
            ->addSubscriberTypeField()
            ->showStoreInfo();
```

**Or  check by email**

```
  $status = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($email);
```

put this code in your module  action page list
as

```
if($status==1){
}
else{
/* redirect to other page */
}
```

Example:

```
public function yourAction(){
{
//$email=email address
$status = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($email);
if($status!=1){
/* redirection to home page*/
 $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
}
//other wise run your code:
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to design a page or possibly a popup, where you can get the email of customers, and you can place the following code in the controller action where that form submits the data:

```
$email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
$subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email);
if($subscriber->getId())
{
 allow the access to site.
}
else{
     $status = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($email);
     if ($status == Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
          Confirmation request has been sent but not confirmed yet.
          restrict the access.
     }else{
        allow the access now.
     }

}
```

not tested but hopefully it will work. The code will first check the existing subscription and subscribe if not already.